# Response [403] Error with Python Requests after adding user-agent and additional headers, Cloudfare blocking access

Tags: python, python-requests

I have repeatedly received <Response [403]> despite adding headers obtained from the chrome developer tool. Would someone with more experience be able to tell me if its possible to access the following url with Python Requests? And if not is there a suggested alternative approach

url='https://www.phosphosite.org/proteinAction.action?id=5848&showAllSites=true'

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url='https://www.phosphosite.org/proteinAction.action?id=5848&showAllSites=true'
headers={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0....'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(result.request.headers)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, though I add to exit all sites and restart my kernel in order to get 200 response

```
 import cloudscraper
    
    scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(browser={'custom': 'ScraperBot/1.0','platform':'windows','mobile':'False'})  # returns a CloudScraper instance
    # Or: scraper = cloudscraper.CloudScraper()  # CloudScraper inherits from requests.Session
    print(scraper.get("https://www.phosphosite.org/proteinAction.action?id=5848&showAllSites=true"))  # => "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Because header key is **lowercase**
How to **solve ?**
Change your header key from:

```
'user-agent'
```

to:

```
'User-Agent'
```

then you get `<Response [200]>` result.

Comment: I attempted that earlier with no success. Cloudfare is currently preventing access based on output